# An error in a for loop in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a for-loop in one of my xslt file, which used to be working:

```
<xsl:template name="for.loop">

<xsl:param name="i"      />
<xsl:param name="count"  />

 <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
    <colspec colname="{concat('c',$i)}"/>
 </xsl:if>

 <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
   <xsl:call-template name="for.loop">
      <xsl:with-param name="i">
          <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
      </xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="count">
          <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
      </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

As you can see, this template is basically a for-loop structure catering for creating "Colspec" nodes of a Cals table model. The parameter I pass to it are just a being index, which should be 1 and a count, which means how many "Colspec" nodes should be created.

Then I call this template like:

```
 <xsl:variable name="value">
    <xsl:value-of select="number($colsCount)+number($multiRowCellCount2)"/>                   
  </xsl:variable>                    

<xsl:attribute name="cols">
                   <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
               </xsl:attribute>   

 <xsl:call-template name="for.loop">
   <xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="count"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

The weird thing is, I reached a point where "$value" is 9, the attribute 9 is assigned correctly for "@cols", but the "Colspecs" nodes have been created 89 times! However, when I try another document, when "$value" is 5, both the "@cols" and #of "Colspecs" are correct.

I am lost here, why does the for loop will repeat 89 times when the actual count is just 9?

Comment: What is your XML Parser, this works fine using the microsoft one.  The only think I can think of is to wrap all your variables in a number clause so in your tests `number($i) &lt;= number($count)` and in your call to the template `number($i) + 1`

Comment: @Bob Vale is exactly right. I can reproduce the error in Saxon HE 9.3 and if I add `number()` to the tests, it works fine.

Comment: @Bob, thanks. This is definitely the solution and I didn't realize this at all. Just curious why it worked for numbers like 5 but not for 9.

Comment: You will also make your life easier by writing `<xsl:variable name="value" select="$colsCount + $multiRowCellCount2"/>` instead of putting an `xsl:value-of` inside of an `xsl:variable`. And instead of `<xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>` simply use '<xsl:with-param name="i" select="1"/>`, instead of '<xsl:with-param name="count"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></xsl:with-param>` use `<xsl:with-param name="count" select="$value"/>`, that way you pass around XPath/XSLT number values and not temporary trees (XSLT 2.0) or result tree fragments (XSLT 1.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you wrap all numeric variables in number function when you are using them as I'm guessing that somewhere your parser is treating them as strings and performing a concatination (so 9+1 becomes 91).. I have no idea why its only happening for 9 and not 5.

So as per my comment the code becomes

```
<xsl:template name="for.loop"> 

  <xsl:param name="i" /> 
  <xsl:param name="count"  /> 

   <xsl:if test="number($i) &lt;= number($count)"> 
     <colspec colname="{concat('c',$i)}"/> 
   </xsl:if> 

   <xsl:if test="number($i) &lt;= number($count)"> 
     <xsl:call-template name="for.loop"> 
       <xsl:with-param name="i"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="number($i) + 1"/> 
       </xsl:with-param> 
       <xsl:with-param name="count"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="$count"/> 
       </xsl:with-param> 
    </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
```

Additionally you are doing the same test in a row, you should be able to just delete the lines

```
   </xsl:if> 

   <xsl:if test="number($i) &lt;= number($count)">
```